# Adding an IF based comparison column

Tags: query, aggregate

I have a table which contains the following columns Table6
ID Place Name Money,

From this I am trying to create a table which contains the following column
Place ,Avg_Money_Place ,High_or_Low , the aim for high/low column is to show equal when this is avg of Place is equal to overall avg, low when it is lower than overall_avg and high elsewhere.

I have a vague idea of how to calculate this with Where structures but am struggling to do with select structures. Here is my feeble attempt
I am struggling to this till now I have tried this

```
Create table Table7 AS
   Select Distinct(Place) , Avg(Money)
     from Table6
    order by ID
```

This gives me the places and the corresponding averages but I am unable to get the hig/low column

I tried using the following function

```
INSERT INTO TABLE7 ( 
  Select High_Low
    CASE
      WHEN AVG(money) < (select AVG(Money) from Table6 ) THEN 'LOW'
      WHEN AVG(money) > (select AVG(Money) from Table6 ) THEN 'HIGH'
      WHEN AVG(money) = (select AVG(Money) from Table6 ) THEN 'EQUAL'
)
```

This did not work ! 
Please help

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I am using the online database provided by the site w3schools , I am not well versed enough to upload the data into MYSQL workbench so I was meddling around with toy data of similiar properties in the service provided by website w3schools . Yes you are correct, I forgot to type the AS keyword there earlier.

Comment: This isn't a sql-standard question so we need to know the dbms or the link where you downloaded it.

Answer (score 2):

The query

```
SELECT Place, 
       AVG(Money)
FROM Table6
GROUP BY Place
```

gives us a place and average money for it.

The query

```
SELECT AVG(Money)
FROM Table6
```

gives us an average money over whole table.

This 2 queries allows us to compare AVG for place and AVG for all (because there are more than 1 table we must add table alias to each field)

```
SELECT t6.Place, 
       AVG(t6.Money) avg_place,
       CASE WHEN AVG(t6.Money) > subquery.avg_all THEN 'High'
            WHEN AVG(t6.Money) < subquery.avg_all THEN 'Low'
            ELSE                                       'Equal' 
       END avg_rank
FROM Table6 t6, ( SELECT AVG(t6_1.Money) avg_all
                  FROM Table6 t6_1 ) subquery
GROUP BY t6.Place
```

And now we can to store the result in new table

```
CREATE TABLE Table7
AS
SELECT t6.Place, 
       AVG(t6.Money) avg_place,
       CASE WHEN AVG(t6.Money) > subquery.avg_all THEN 'High'
            WHEN AVG(t6.Money) < subquery.avg_all THEN 'Low'
            ELSE                                       'Equal' 
       END avg_rank
FROM Table6 t6, ( SELECT AVG(t6_1.Money) avg_all
                  FROM Table6 t6_1 ) subquery
GROUP BY t6.Place
```

Comment: I specifically have build a solution where we obtain average money over a source table. But I think you need average from averages - not average over source table, but average over first query. I think it will be helpful for you to try to fix it yourself. Use step-by-step method as shown above.

Comment: I think averaging over averages might give me a result which isn't the actual average. So I thought about it but am planning to go for average of the source table6

Comment: Yes... all you need is replace the source table in 2nd query with proper subquery, and respectively edit all below queries. Do it with accuracy, and everything will be OK. While editing you may check all intermediate results on a sample data for a correctness.